# I can't get this AJAX to fire in ASP.Net/C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using the ASP.Net ScriptManager control. It's on the page already.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="cpBox" Visible="false" runat="server">
            <!-- jQuery plugin goes here -->
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlColorChart" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The C#:

```
protected void ddlColorChart_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlColorChart.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        // cpBox.Visible = true;
        /* StringBuilder colorPicker = new StringBuilder();
        colorPicker.Append("$(document).ready(function() {");
        colorPicker.Append("$('#<%=colorPickerBox.ClientID %>').ColorPicker({ flat: true });");
        colorPicker.Append("})");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(colorPickerBox, this.GetType(), "colorPicker", colorPicker.ToString(),  true);
        */
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=colorPicker_Box.ClientID %>').ColorPicker({ flat: true });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, I tried using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the jQuery plugin to show. I tried with jQuery AJAX and got lost.

Edit: I know that the plugin works if I keep it in a regular div. Once I add `'runat="server",'` it stops working (which makes sense). Is there a way for me to accomplish this using ASP.Net AJAX without the container for the plugin being a server control?

Comment: what exact plugin are you trying to use and what specified error do you get in the console?

Comment: I don't get an error in the console, unless I use the RegisterStartupScript. The plugin is: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= %>` is a server code; JavaScript cannot execute it. So you want to pass control's client id from server side.

```
colorPicker.Append("$('#" + colorPickerBox.ClientID " + 
   "').ColorPicker({ flat: true });");
```

Updated: If `ColorPicker` is not a server control, it is even easier -

```
colorPicker.Append("$('#colorPickerBox').ColorPicker({ flat: true });");
```

Comment: So this goes in the StringBuilder? (never mind, that's obvious). Do I need to put the `<script>` tags in the StringBuilder?

Comment: That depends on where colorPickerBox is located. If you access colorPickerBox inside StringBuilder, I'll say yes. Btw, is colorPickerBox server control?